# Data replaced instead of insereted using SQLite on android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator, android-widget

I am writing an android app which requires the records to be added one after another.
When user types in the correct pin his profile is updated by a connected component to pin.
But my app is updating instead of inserting or adding a new record. Here is my code please help me out

```
//Database
    SQLiteDatabase db=mydbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    //Openining the database

        db=this.openOrCreateDatabase("mm.db",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        try
        {
            //Retriving the pin from db
            Cursor c=db.query("pin_table",null,null,null,null,null,null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            boolean matched=false;
            while(c.isAfterLast()== false)
            {
                String hsname=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
                String dpass=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("pin"));
                int id=c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                if(epass.equals(dpass))
                {

                    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
                    value.put("reg_hs",id);
                    //Inserting into the table 
                    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO hereg(reg_hs) VALUES("+id+");");

                    //db.insert("registered", null,value);
                    Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),"Successfully added "+ hsname,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    matched=true;
                    finish();
                    break;
                }
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            if(!matched)
                Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),"Please enter the correct Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
            c.close();
        }           
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error","Error",e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(db!=null)
            {
                db.close();

            }
        }
}
```

I used both execSql and also db.insert(commented) giving the same result. Is it because of the while loop?

My problem is all records are deleted and only record is shown and latest value is written across it :(

Comment: Why you are doing `finish()` this will cause your activity to finish, is that is regular?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use finish() unless you absolutely need to.

If you must, I suggest synchronizing the two methods (inserting and finishing) with a lock Object.

When the insert finishes, call lockObject.notify() and this will allow the activity to finish.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

Just another thought.  You may try using an AsyncTask with doInBackGround() containing the database access, and onPostExecute() calling activity.finish().  This is a bit more explicit way to handle the problem.

Comment: Is it needed to lock? He is doing the insertion in same thread (I guess so)

Comment: I am using finish to complete the activity and return back to main screen. Even removing finish doesn't solve the problem

Comment: With database transactions like this, they are sometimes handled in a seperate thread (by the Android system).  It is good programming practice to ensure any database/network accesses are threadsafe.

Comment: It seems he does the transaction in the current thread, if he has another thread that requires transactions to the database than he must do thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

No need of finish() as I said in the comment that will finish the entire activity.

You can rewrite the statement in the while loop like this

```
while(c.isAfterLast()== false || matched==true)
{

}
```

which will stop the looping when matched is found (and stop looping if `isAfterLast()`, ofcourse)

Comment: I am using finish to complete the activity and return back to main screen. Even removing finish doesn't solve the problem